# How to properly approach threading with Room

Tags: android, android-room, android-thread

I am confused about *Room* and can not find an answer in the documentation.

So, the library enforces using queries on a separate Thread, which is understandable. However, it seems that Delete queries are not included in this limitation and can be freely called from the UI Thread. They also always return a raw output value, without a chance to wrap it in an Observable.

**What is the correct way to use the delete call in *Room* then**? Should it be run on a separate Thread? If not, what about performance and concurrent modifications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use LiveData to retrieve data from Room, it's executed in worker thread. For, other queries you can use Executors and Repository pattern. You can check out this page for [guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide).

You can check out this [link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/) for Rx and other architecture component samples.

---

Analysis note by the question author:

In the sample they **use a `Completable` to wrap the *Room* delete call** and then **schedule it onto the `io()` scheduler**, reacting to the empty complete and any errors. That specific code can be found [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/BasicRxJavaSampleKotlin/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability).

Comment: I have a repository pattern, based on Rx (no LiveData and no real chance to refactor into it). Should I then wrap the delete calls into Singles and subscribe them on a background Thread? If so, why doesn't Room's Rx integration offer Single returns on deletes in the first place?

Comment: I don't use Rx, you can check out these [tutorials](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/) for detailed usage.

Comment: Amazing, this is exactly what I needed! :-D Please update the answer with this link, so I can accept it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: I added a small note with the roundup of the code under the link you provided and also accepted the answer. Thanks again!

Comment: It's good to have that note. I will check it out again after i learnt RxJava. Thanks also.